When defining a free module, is the action of a ring $R$ on itself as a module implied to be multiplication?
In the free modules section of Atiyah & MacDonald, they define a free $R$-module $M$ as any $R$-module such that
$M \cong \bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i$
where each $M_i \cong R$ as an $R$-module, and $I$ is some index set. I was curious why we care about free modules, and from looking around, I found that they are precisely modules with a basis.
I was originally thinking that maybe any time a ring $R$ acts on itself, that module has a 1 element R-basis, but I think a found a counterexample to that by looking at $\mathbb{F}_2 \times \mathbb{F}_2$ and mapping $(a, b)$ to $(a, a)$ before multiplication, i.e. $(a, b) \cdot (x, y) = (ax, ay)$. So, what I'm wondering is in the definition they gave, is it implied that in each copy of the direct sum, R is acting on itself by multiplication?

Yes, it's implied.
